# Problems changing e-commerce transaction data in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, universal-analytics, event-tracking

I am trying to amend an erroneous Google Analytics e-commerce transaction that I registered while testing. I have created a standout HTML page on the website with the following code, expecting it to change the transaction. After visiting the page and waiting 24 hours, I see no change to the e-commerce transaction in Analytics.

I am making sure that the transaction ID is the same as the original transaction.

I used the Google Tag Manager plugin for Chrome to make sure that there were no errors with my JS code and see nothing on the developer console when loading the page.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('require', 'ecommerce');
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
  // ga('send', 'pageview');

    ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
      'id': 'tok_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',         // Transaction ID. Required.
      'affiliation': 'XXXXXX XXXXXX Website',       // Affiliation or store name.
      'revenue': '100.00',                          // Grand Total.
      'shipping': '0',                              // Shipping.
      'tax': '20.00'                                // Tax.
    });

    ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
      'id': 'tok_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',          // Transaction ID. Required.
      'name': 'XXX XXXXXX XXXX Membership',         // Product name. Required.
      'sku': 'product-name',                        // SKU/code.
      'category': 'Special Offers/XXX XXXXXX XXXX', // Category or variation.
      'price': '100.00',                            // Unit price.
      'quantity': '1'                               // Quantity.
    });

    ga('ecommerce:send');

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You may need to do a refund and then repurchase instead of trying to overwrite the existing transaction.

Comment: I have tried doing a refund against the transaction IDs using this guide: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6014861?hl=en - after 24 hours, the transactions remain unchanged